# Optimizer bug or programming error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, visual-studio-2012

First of all: I know that most optimization bugs are due to programming errors or relying on facts which may change depending on optimization settings (floating point values, multithreading issues, ...).

However I experienced a very hard to find bug and am somewhat unsure if there is any way to prevent these kind of errors from happening without turning the optimization off. Am I missing something? Could this really be an optimizer bug? Here's a simplified example:

```
struct Data {
  int    a;
  int    b;
  double c;
};

struct Test {
  void optimizeMe();

  Data m_data;
};

void Test::optimizeMe() {
  Data * pData; // Note that this pointer is not initialized!

  bool first = true;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if (first) {
      first = false;

      pData = &m_data;

      pData->a = i * 10;
      pData->b = i * pData->a;
      pData->c = pData->b / 2;
    } else {
      pData->a = ++i;
    } // end if
  } // end for
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Test test;
  test.optimizeMe();
  return 0;
}
```

The real program of course has a lot more to do than this. But it all boils down to the fact that instead of accessing m_data directly, a (previously unitialized) pointer is being used. As soon as I add enough statements to the `if (first)`-part, the optimizer seems to change the code to something along these lines:

```
if (first) {
  first = false;

  // pData-assignment has been removed!

  m_data.a = i * 10;
  m_data.b = i * m_data.a;
  m_data.c = m_data.b / m_data.a;
} else {
  pData->a = ++i; // This will crash - pData is not set yet. 
} // end if
```

As you can see, it replaces the unnecessary pointer dereference with a direct write to the member struct. However it does not do this in the `else`-branch. It also removes the `pData`-assignment. Since the pointer is now still unitialized, the program will crash in the `else`-branch.

Of course there are various things which could be improved here, so you might blame it on the programmer:

- Forget about the pointer and do what the optimizer does - use `m_data` directly.
- Initialize pData to nullptr - that way the optimizer knows that the `else`-branch will fail if the pointer is never assigned. At least it seems to solve the problem in my test-environment.
- Move the pointer assignment in front of the loop (effectively initializing `pData` with `&m_data`, which then could also be a reference instead of a pointer (for good measure). This makes sense because pData is needed in all cases so there is no reason to do this inside the loop.

The code is obviously smelly, to say the least, and I'm not trying to "blame" the optimizer for doing this. But I'm asking: *What am I doing wrong? The program might be ugly, but it's valid code...*

I should add that I'm using VS2012 with C++/CLI and v110_xp-Toolset. Optimization is set to /O2. Please also note that if you really want to reproduce the problem (that's not really the point of this question though) you need to play around with the complexity of the program. This is a very simplified example and the optimizer sometimes doesn't remove the pointer assignment. Hiding `&m_data` behind a function seems to "help".

**EDIT:**

*Q: How do I know that the compiler is optimizing it to something like the example provided?*

A: I'm not very good at reading assembler, I have looked at it however and have made 3 observations which make me believe that it's behaving this way:

1. As soon as optimization kicks in (adding more assignments usually does the trick) the pointer assignment has no associated assembler statement. It also hasn't been moved up to the declaration, so it's really left uninitialized it seems (at least to me).
2. In cases where the program crashes, the debugger skips the assignment statement. In cases where the program runs without problems, the debugger stops there.
3. If I watch the content of `pData` and the content of `m_data` while debugging, it clearly shows that all assignments in the `if`-branch have an effect on `m_data` and `m_data` receives the correct values. The pointer itself it still pointing to the same uninitialized value it had from the beginning. Therefore I have to assume that it is in fact not using the pointer to make the assignments at all.

*Q: Does it have to do anything with i (Loop unrolling)?*

A: No, the actual program actually uses do { ... } while() to loop over a SQL SELECT-resultset so the iteration count is completely runtime-specific and cannot be predetermined by the compiler.

Comment: Reduce this to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @djechlin: Bugs affected by optimization may be hard to reduce to small code samples. The question explicitly states this is already a simplified example.

Comment: cannot clearly explain an idea yet, but does it work in the same way if you make class instead if struct?

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly or are you just assuming that the optimizer removes the `pData` assignment?

Comment: Does the simplified example as posted misbehave?

Comment: VC++ wouldn't even compile this. you have to init pData.

Comment: Yeah... have you verified that this is happening? Or are you just speculating?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I still expect and request the OP reduce the code to a state where most perturbations will leave the bug in tact, and I expect to see comments explaining what lines when perturbed make the bug vanish.

Comment: @evilruff, there is no difference in how the struct and class are being compiled in C++.

Comment: Does the real code use `i` to access some array/other memory and then goes out of bounds because there are two `++i` in most iterations of the loop?

Comment: @Excelcius: Please provide two separate complete code samples, one in which the problem appears and one in which it does not. Specify which is which, of course. They should be as similar as you can get, that is, the minimum possible change between them. (If there is any change that can be made to make one more similar to, but still different from the other, and still be compilable, then make that change. It will either have the problem or not, and it then replaces one of the two samples. Repeat until no change is possible.)

Comment: Microsoft state to use the highest warning levels to avoid subtle hard to find bugs, I believe this is one of them, init pData to nullptr and  its likely the issue will go away.

Comment: The original code doesn't have `reinterpret_cast` or a C-style cast in it, does it? This smells like a strict-alias violation in the small chance it's not an optimizer bug.

Comment: Most likely explanation is, that the real code is subtly different, and a code path where value is left uninitialized is indeed possible. But optimizer bug is not out of the question either, of course. Ask compiler to produce assembly output to verify that initialization is indeed missing. Look for loop unrolling, might be related to that, especially if it really is a compiler bug.

Comment: The compiler may assume undefined behavior never happens & elide code segments that rely on it. For example `int *p; int b = *p; if(p) {...}` A good optimizer will get rid of the if check. There might be subtle instances of undefined behavior in the extra lines in the if block causing the compiler to elide the assignment. Take a look at www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/download/attachments/80379909/Dangerous%20Optimizations%20-%20Complete%20Version.pdf

Comment: Wow, lots of questions here :)

Comment: @djechlin I tried to post a working example using codepad - however it timed out, will retry tomorrow. I managed to extend it to the point where the crash does occur.

Comment: @evilruff Changing it to class has no effect (it is a class in the orginal code).

Comment: @sth I have looked at the assembly code, but I'm not very proficient in asm. I'll add a short statement in the question to explain how I got the idea that this is what the optimization is doing.

Comment: @yngum My VC++ compiles this - might be due to warning level

Comment: @Excelcius agree.. had some weird idea.. sorry

Comment: compilers have a hard time getting pointers to memory like this right anyway, so I avoid them in general.  I think you have fallen into that trap.  It is  50/50 I would say 50% user for doing something risky 50% compiler for failing to catch the dependency.

Comment: `if (first)` is always true. So, the crash part will never be executed.

Comment: @strange-corner: Not true, `first` is immediately set to false after the condition, causing every following iteration of the loop to enter the crash part. This post is very old and it was indeed an optimizer bug by the very peculiar C++/CLI-compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sure looks like an bug to me. It's fine for the optimizer to eliminate the unnecessary redirection, but it should not eliminate the assignment to `pData`.

Of course, you can work around the problem by assigning to `pData` before the loop (at least in this simple example). I gather that the problem in your actual code isn't as easily resolved.

Comment: Actually removing the pointer as a whole has been the solution in the actual code. The code is over 15 years old and most bugs like these are easy to resolve because the code simply needs some simple refactoring. Finding the bug is a totally different story.

Comment: Since I am fairly sure now that this has been a compiler bug I will accept this as the answer. As soon as I have filed a bugreport with microsoft, I will add the link to the question, so there will be a real reproducable example available. I think it's more of a C++/CLI thing though, the normal compiler didn't mess up.

Answer (score 1):

I also vote for an optimizer bug if it is really reproducible in this example. To overrule the optimizer you could try to declare `pData` as `volatile`.